# How can I remove the gap above my carousel?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.6 and I can't remove the gap above the carousel. I've tried adding `margin-top: -20px;` in the carousel base class and well no luck :(

Here my code.

**HTML:**

```
  <!-- Carousel
================================================== -->
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img class="first-slide" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="First slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Example headline.</h1>
          <p>Note: If you're viewing this page via a <code>file://</code> URL, the "next" and "previous" Glyphicon buttons on the left and right might not load/display properly due to web browser security rules.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="second-slide" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Second slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
          <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="third-slide" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Third slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
          <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>



       <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div><!-- /.carousel -->
```

**CSS:**

```
 /* Carousel base class */
.carousel {
  height: 50px;
    top: -20px; 
    width:100%; 
    margin: 0px auto;
}
/* Since positioning the image, we need to help out the caption */
.carousel-caption {
  z-index: 10;
}

/* Declare heights because of positioning of img element */
.carousel .item {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #777;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

/* RESPONSIVE CSS
-------------------------------------------------- */

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  /* Navbar positioning foo */

  .navbar-wrapper .container {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
  }
  .navbar-wrapper .navbar {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }

  /* The navbar becomes detached from the top, so we round the corners */
  .navbar-wrapper .navbar {
    border-radius: 4px;
  }

  /* Bump up size of carousel content */
  .carousel-caption p {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 21px;
    line-height: 1.4;
  }

  .featurette-heading {
    font-size: 50px;
  }
}
```

I have tried adding `margin-top: -20px;` in classes such as `.carousel` but no luck :(

Comment: there is no gap at the top of this carousel: http://www.bootply.com/1LnaP2xA1Z - there must be something in your code causing it.  If you inspect the element, is there any other style applied to it or the element above it?

Comment: Thanks you, I inspected my homepage and my navbar for some reason had a margin-bottom. Thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

try add:

```
body {
  padding-top: 70px;
}
```

Comment: That just added 70px above my navbar :(

Comment: How would this solve a gap above the carousel?  At most, it would just increase that gap

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, you said you added `margin-top:-20px`, but your example code says you added `top:-20px`; When I ran the code in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/om3vovLb/1/) there wasn't any space at the top.

However, I'd like to try and help, so I'd say don't alter the `.carousel` class directly, but instead target the `#myCarousel` and make your `top: -20px` there. I make this recommendation in case boot strap utilizes `.carousel` in other places besides the container.

However, this can alter the way the rest of the page handles, so I would recommend looking at the element holding the `#myCarousel` since the fiddle shows no problems. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think the gap is occurring because of navbar and for that you should try the below code.

---

```
.navbar{
    margin-bottom: 0px!important;
}
```

I hope it works...!